# What does a method name mean inside its own method?

Tags: ruby, methods

I see some coder use this code:

```
def client
  client ||= OAuth2::Client.new(G_API_CLIENT, G_API_SECRET, bla)
end

get "/auth" do
  redirect client.auth_code.authorize_url(blabla)
end
```

what does `client` mean inside `def client`? Wouldn't it be equal to:

```
def client
  OAuth2::Client.new(G_API_CLIENT, G_API_SECRET, bla)
end
```

When I try it on irb:

```
> def test
>   p 'called'
>   test ||= 1
> end
=> nil
> test
"called"
=> 1
> test
"called"
=> 1
```

so the conclusion would be that method a name inside the same method definition has no effect except for recursion.

Comment: It should be @client ||= ...

Comment: yeah, maybe it's should be `@client` instead of `client`

Comment: Not maybe. 100%, this code is a mistake.

Comment: this is the source: https://github.com/ephekt/gmail-oauth2-sinatra/blob/master/app.rb

Comment: And, in that code, it is a mistake. It works, but it's not by design. The value being returned by `||=` is the return value of the method, and never is the value of `client`, which is a local value and immediately discarded outside that method. Always. The lesson here is, don't immediately believe, or trust, the code you find on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so the conclusion would be, that method name inside method name has no effect except for recursion?

No,it is not in your example.`test` is local variable to the method `test`.

See below:

```
def test
  test ||= 1
  defined? test
end

test # => "local-variable"
```

Now see if you skip `test ||= 1`,then `test` will be a method call and if you call `test` from there,then you would get `stack level too deep (SystemStackError)`.

```
def test
  defined? test
end

test # => "method"
```

Comment: It would be worth noting that Ruby treats `test` as a local variable *because* you assign to it. If the assignment was not there, it would be a method call (and result in a stack overflow error).

Comment: but on this case, because it's the last statement inside `def`, so there are no effect, right?

Comment: @AlexD you are 100% correct.. I was just going to put that line in my answer too.. :)